# Какое из двух предложений правильно оформлено с точки зрения стилистики?

Tags: стилистика

Какой вариант правильный?

1. Направить кандидатуру Иванова И.И. на должность Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте Российской Федерации на согласование с Уполномоченным по правам человека в Российской Федерации.
   *Или:*
2. Направить кандидатуру Иванова И.И. Уполномоченному по правам человека в Российской Федерации для согласования на должность Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте Российской Федерации.

Comment: ну второй просто не подходит, ибо не ясно, кто на ком стоял. Перебор уполномоченных - и все в перемешку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Направить кандидатуру Иванова И.И. на должность Уполномоченного по
> правам человека в субъекте Российской Федерации на согласование с
> Уполномоченным по правам человека в Российской Федерации.

Лучше бы поправить, ибо очень тяжеловесно, канцелярит ключом бъет. Но здесь хотя бы понятно, кто куда направлен. Чего не скажешь о втором варианте.

Нормальным языком я бы сказал как-то так:

***Направить предложение о назначении Иванова И. И. на должность уполномоченного... в субъекте на согласование уполномоченному... в РФ.***

Но тут дело такое, что бюрократы крайне не любят отступления от известной и принятой у них формы, с этим приходится считаться.  Так что рекомендовать императивно этот вариант не могу.

(+)
В отношении заглавной буквы в слове Уполномоченный - это отдельный разговор, и не простой. Используйте лучше привычный вам вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:  *Направить кандидатуру Иванова И.И. на должность Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте Российской Федерации **для согласования** с Уполномоченным по правам человека в Российской Федерации.*

**1.  Выбор предлога**

Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант правильный:

–  отправлять документы НА согласование;

–  отправлять документы ДЛЯ согласования.

Или может оба варианта правильны, но один из них предпочтителен?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:  **Возможны оба варианта.**

**2. Пример:**

Кандидатам на должность главного бухгалтера учреждения или заместителям руководителя по экономике и финансам после направления документов **для согласования** необходимо связаться с приемной первого заместителя руководителя Департамента Г.В.
https://jurst24.ru/soglasovanie-kandidatury-na-dolzhnost-obrazec.html

3. Вопрос о выборе падежного управления часто задается в Сети, одно из мнений звучит так: Договор передаётся **ДЛЯ согласования**. А решение по документу **НА согласование** принимается или не принимается.

Предлог ДЛЯ в большей степени обозначает целевую направленность действий, а предлог НА используется в двух вариантах: направить на согласование и документ на согласование (функция несогласованного определения).

4. Вероятно, надо различать  и такие варианты:  направить для согласования куда-либо и направить для согласования с кем-либо, например:

В пресс-службе ведомства говорят, что он согласован с Минэкономразвития и **направлен на согласование в другие профильные ведомства.**

Разрешение выдается при условии, если  лицо обязуется не публиковать какие-либо работы без предварительного представления текста **для согласования с Председателем** Санкт-Петербургского третейского суда.